# Undefined reference to class_name<template_argument>function_name(variable)?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, undefined-reference

I'm getting a fatal linking error in the code below, it says:

```
]+0x10)||undefined reference to `base<node>::pass_derived(node)'|
```

I wanted to define a `base` class which has a pointer called `poly_type` and the `base` class can also "access" from within itself another class called `derived`. The problem I run into is line `poly_type->pass_derived(n);` where the compiler doesn't want to see the derived class where I tried to pass an object of type `node`. I'm guessing this is a limitation of C++, if so let me know. Heres the broken code,

**edit** seems like this has been asked somewhere else, I updated the source to reflect that opinion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: The definition of `base`'s member function `pass_derived` is missing.

Comment: creating object of derived class in it's base class is certainly wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no definition of pass_derived in the base class.
You declare it as a virtual function but only define it in the derived class.
Because it instantiates base in the main function, the compiler tries to generate code for base but it does not find a definition for pass_derived.

You could add a default implementation - even if it is just empty.

As for whether you can eventually get it to call derived::pass_derived instead... :) good luck, it looks like fun.  You are building your own version of inheritance?

Comment: "You could add a default implementation - even if it is just empty."  Yup I just added an empty `virtual void pass_derived(T data)
        {

        }` inside `base` class.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
template < class T>
class base
{
    // ...
    virtual void pass_derived(T data);
};
```

You declared `pass_derived` as `virtual` but not pure `virtual`. Therefore, the linker raises an error if you don't provide an implementation.

Either you provide an implementation or (which I believe is your intent) you declare it pure `virtual`:

```
    virtual void pass_derived(T data) = 0;
```

but then you cannot instantiate `base<T>` and must work only with pointers or references to `base` (which actually point/refer to `derived`).

Comment: Yes I tried using `virtual void pass_derived(T data) = 0;` but then it complains about `base<node> b1(1);
    base<node> b0(0);`?

Comment: "but then you cannot instantiate base<T> and must work only with pointers or references to base (which actually point/refer to derived)."  I tried what Graham Griffiths said it works now!

Comment: @lost_with_coding: I've updated the answer to say exactly that.